# CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'char[]'

Tags: c#

I'm new to C and don't understand the error as in the title above, the code I have is as follows, but the error is show on line 7, (result);

```
public async static Task<RootObject> GetSensor(bool on)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.71/api/apikey/sensors");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));//result is where the error is generated
        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Does `.ToArray()` work after `ReadAsStreamAsync()`? *edit* Tried it and does not

Comment: [`ReadAsStreamAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the stream but you pass it to `GetBytes` which takes a `byte[]`(or string)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing directly

```
var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(result);
```

without the `var ms = new MemoryStream(` line. `ReadObject` accepts a `Stream` as an input, and `result` is a `Stream`.

Comment: perfect, Ive changed the code as above and it works without error, appreciate the help